# unable to execute after loading second shell /bin/bash?

Tags: bash, scripts

I went through a shell scripting tutorial explaining about global variables (`export`).
I encountered a do-it-yourself example to illustrate the concept of global variables in shell scripting, and I tried it by:

```
$ cat trial

vech=Bus
echo $vech
/bin/bash
echo "before empty line"
echo $vech
echo "after empty line"
vech=Car
echo $vech
exit
echo $vech
```

The expected output for this program was:

```
Bus
before empty line 
after empty line
Car
Bus
```

But I got :

```
$ chmod 777 trial
$ ./trial
Bus
$
```

where I am getting wrong?, I am new this flavor please help me.

Comment: That looks like a set of commands which you should be entering on the terminal, not run as a script. The second `echo` and everything up to the `exit` are meant to be commands to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: thanx @muru ,well by using /bin/sh it provides me with prompt $,,but not with /bin/bash??

Comment: What @muru means is that `/bin/bash` does not receive the lines after it as input.  You could replace it with `sleep 1` and the script would not be much different (except now you have to explicitly exit from Bash before the script will continue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this using a *here-document* :

```
vech=Bus
echo $vech
/bin/bash<<EOF
echo "before empty line"
echo $vech
echo "after empty line"
vech=Car
echo $vech
exit
EOF
echo $vech
```

Comment: thanx@sputnick ,,but this program has changed the essence of globlal variable explanation,,because it prints::anupam@JAZZ:~/Desktop$ chmod +x trial_ask_ubuntu
         anupam@JAZZ:~/Desktop$ ./trial_ask_ubuntu
         Bus
         before empty line
         Bus
         after empty line
         Bus
         Bus
         anupam@JAZZ:~/Desktop$

Comment: The contents of the here document are evaluated before they are passed to the subshell.  Use single quotes in `<<'EOF'` to prevent that.  However, you will need to `export vech` if you want it to be defined in the subshell.